# ELOQUENT ORM subgrupos de query dan error

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-7

tengo un SELECT que evalúa dos condiciones, la primera de ellas es obligatoria y la segunda es un subgrupo donde al menos una debería dar "true" para que se cumpla el SELECT general.
El asunto es que según recomendaciones de la documentación de ELOQUENT, en estos casos la mejor opción es pasar un "closure" como segundo parámetro (el grupo de opciones) pero el asunto es que hasta allá adentro tengo que enviar una variable a validar y cuando intento hacerlo, la funcion "closure" falla y lanza un error. Esto es lo que tengo hasta ahora.

```
$modelo = Escuela::where("nombre", $nombre)
  ->where(function($q, $b){
  $q->where("apellido","like","%" . $b . "%")
  ->orWhere("ciudad","like","%" . $b . "%");
  })->select("id","nombre","apellido")->get();
```

Asumiendo una los valores:

```
$nombre = "John"
$b = "gua"
```

Debería quedar mas o menos así:

```
select * from users where name = 'John' and (apellido LIKE '%gua%' or ciudad  LIKE '%gua%'),
```

Pero me lanza un error diciendo que el número de argumentos del "closure" no es el correcto

Que me estoy perdiendo?

Comment: Agrega por favor el mensaje de error exacto que obtienes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A mí me parece que lo único que faltaba era pasar a tus variables [al contexto de la función](https://www.php.net/manual/es/functions.anonymous.php)  de esta forma:

```
->where(function($query) use ($algo, $otro) {
    ......
})
```

Y tu consulta quedaría así:

```
$modelo = Escuela::where("nombre", $nombre)
                ->where(function($q) use ($b) {
                    $q->where("apellido","like","%" . $b . "%")
                        ->orWhere("ciudad","like","%" . $b . "%");
            })->select("id","nombre","apellido")->get();
```

Comment: Gracias ... es exacto lo que esperaba, funcionó perfecto!, estaba seguro que habría una solución más decente que la que le dí en principio jaja

Answer (score 1):

No creo que sea la mejor solución pero no logré hacer que funcionara tratando de pasar una variable ... entonces la solución "de palo" que usé fue declarar una constante antes de hacer la consulta y meter dicha constante dentro del query:

```
define("E_CAD_BUSCAR", $cad);

$modelo = Escuela::where("nombre", $nombre)
->where(function($q){
 $q->where("apellido","like","%" . E_CAD_BUSCAR . "%")
->orWhere("ciudad","like","%" . E_CAD_BUSCAR . "%");
})->select("id","nombre","apellido")->get()
```

Comment: Si, perfectamente, mas detalles en: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/queries#where-clauses